# In MATLAB, I want to convert a vector of text elements into numbers in order to plot them.

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I want to convert a vector of text elements into numbers in order to plot them.

For example, say I have the following data

```
team = [blue green blue yellow green blue];
score = [20 45 74 10 11 42];
```

I want use scatter like this

```
scatter(team, score)
```

so that along the x-axis I have three (i.e. the number of unique elements in `team`) labels (blue, green and yellow) and the y-axis shows each score.

So I need to convert the vector `team` into numbers, e.g. `team = [1 2 1 3 2 1];` or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the text elements are in a cell array, like so:

```
team = {'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'};
```

It isn't possible to make a normal vector / array with multiple strings, as this would basically create a single string that concatenates all of these strings together.  You'd have to split them up into a cell array... now onto your question.

You can use the third output parameter of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).  This output basically assigns each **unique** element in an array or cell array a unique ID number.  In this case, if you did:

```
[~,~,id] = unique(team)
```

... we would get:

```
id =

 1
 2
 1
 3
 2
 1
```

... which is exactly what you want!

---

As a bonus for you, we can easily plot this, changing the `x` axis to each of those labels.  In other words:

```
score = [20 45 74 10 11 42].'; %// Transpose as id is transposed '
plot(id, score, 'b.', 'MarkerSize', 16);  % // Plot the points
                                          % // Marker size is 16
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:3); %// Only set three ticks to 
                        %// be visible as there are 3 IDs
xlim([0 4]); %// Make the x-axis bigger
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', ...
   {'blue', 'green', 'yellow'}); %// Change the numeric labels to text
grid; %// Put a grid on
```

... and this is the figure I get:

[image]